# Multiple comma separated values in columns into a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table

| Userid | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5,1234 | 3,8967 | 2,3245 | 7,5658 |
| 2 | 2,3245 | 5,5658 | 6,4567 | 20,9876 |

I need to separate each comma separated column into the same fields like this:

| Userid | refid | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1234 |
| 1 | 3 | 8967 |
| 1 | 2 | 3245 |
| 1 | 7 | 5658 |
| 2 | 2 | 3245 |
| 2 | 5 | 5658 |

and so on. I have messed around with `string_split`, `cross apply`, etc, but I can't seem to get it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show us your attempt... its very very common question, there are loads of duplicates out there.

Comment: Can there be more than two values (ie more than one comma) in these columns?

Comment: no, will only be 2 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) your table to get `Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5` as a single column, then use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` string functions to get the desired output.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT Userid, colx
  FROM   
   (
     SELECT Userid, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
     FROM table_name
   ) T  
  UNPIVOT  
  (
    colx FOR c IN (Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)  
  ) UP
)

SELECT Userid, 
       LEFT(colx, CHARINDEX(',', colx) - 1) ref,
       RIGHT(colx, LEN(colx) - CHARINDEX(',', colx)) val
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Userid
```

You may also use it directly without the CTE, but CTE makes it clearer.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5ii0aa0E)